# Get size of video track

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, twilio-api

I use Twilio API to create video chat between two users.
First user video pic must be a smaller circle on top of the second user pic.

Second user uses USB camera and I get "horizontal rectangle" video, so I need move circle with my video on this rectangle:

[image]

I try to get CMVideoDimensions:

```
extension VideoChatViewController: TVIParticipantDelegate {
    func participant(_ participant: TVIParticipant, addedVideoTrack videoTrack: TVIVideoTrack) {
        logMessage(messageText: "Participant \(participant.identity) added video track")

        if (self.participant == participant) {
            videoTrack.attach(self.remoteView)
            let dimensions = videoTrack.videoDimensions
            let height = dimensions.height
            let width = dimensions.width
            print ("\(height) ; \(width)")
        }
    }
}
```

But I got height = 0 and width = 0.
How can I get size of the video track ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I've spoken with the Video team and I'm told that `videoDimensions` is going to be deprecated from the `TVIVideoTrack` class in upcoming betas as it wasn't working particularly well, as you've discovered.

The better way to get `videoDimensions` is from a `TVIVideoViewRenderer`. Here's a snippet for adding a video view renderer to a video track:

```
let renderer = TVIVideoViewRenderer.init(delegate: self)
videoTrack.addRenderer(renderer)
renderer.view.frame = view.bounds
renderer.view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
view.addSubview(renderer.view)
```

Let me know if this helps.